# R: lm and lmer produce the same results

Tags: r, hierarchical-data, lm, lme4, mixed-models

I recently conducted a study in which I divided participants into two conditions. They rated different items. I wanted to test whether their ratings differed between the two conditions. Because these items differed substantially and I was taking many measurements per participant, I decided to add at least random intercepts for items (coded as "item") and participants (coded as "id").

I fit the following model with the `lme4` package:

```
lmer(y ~ condition + (1|id) + (1|item), dfLong)
```

But, then I fit the following simple linear model to the index measure created by averaging all responses for each participant:

```
lm(itemMean ~ condition, dfWide)
```

And the results were **exactly the same** as those I got with LMM! If I remove the random intercept for items, i.e. (1|Item), then the results remain unchanged! Does anyone know why a linear model fitted to the aggregate (averaged response) data gives the same standard errors as LMM with random intercepts for items and participants?

Below I have attached the mwe in R.

```
dfWide <- data.frame(
  condition=c('a','a','b'),
  item1=c(55,30,65),
  item2=c(35,30,45),
  item3=c(45,30,40),
  itemMean=c(45,30,50)
)

dfLong <- data.frame(
  id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
  condition=c('a','a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b'),
  item=c('item1','item2','item3','item1','item2','item3','item1','item2','item3'),
  y=c(55,35,45,30,30,30,65,45,40)
)

summary(lmer(y ~ condition + (1|id) + (1|item), dfLong))
summary(lm(itemMean ~ condition, dfWide))
```

PS: removing random intercepts for participants (1|id) produces results that I expected, with lower standard errors. Is there anything wrong with the random effects structure I used in this particular study?

Comment: The results are not exactly the same. The standard errors differ substantially.

Comment: @RobertLong - are you sure that SEs for the effect of condition differ? On my laptop it's SE = 12.99 in both cases

Comment: I can't be sure without running the code, but unless there is zero variation among the intercepts then the standard error for the intercept in the `lm` model should be smaller than that for the `lmer` model. This is a balanced design, so likely nothing unusual here.

Comment: Yes, for intercepts, standard errors are slightly lower for `lm` than for `lmer`, but standard errors for the effects of the condition are still the same, which is rather weird; what is the point of doing LMM if they produce the same results as `lm`?

Comment: Like I said, the results are not the same. The point estimates might be the same (since the design is balanced) and even if the SEs are the same for `condition`, the p-values will not be the same, since the denominator degrees of freedom will differ, so inferences will be different. Also, if your interest was in variance components, then, obviously, `lm` will not be appropriate.

Comment: @RobertLong - as coefficients and standard errors for the effect of condition are the same, then t-values and corresponding p-values are also the same for the effect of condition on the dependent measure. In both, `lmer` and `lm` I get p = .51; so that part of the results that I am interested in (the effect of condition) is still the same; I doubt anybody is interested in interpreting intercepts per se, but I may be wrong.

Comment: P-values are not the same because the denominator degrees of freedom are not the same.

Comment: in both, lm and lmer as described above I see df = 198. Can you run the code and see if you also get the same output?

Comment: How do you get 198 degrees of freedom with (long-format) dataset that has 9 rows? Apart from that the standard error of the *condition* effect depends on whether you use REML or not to fit the mixed effects model.

Comment: Oops, you are right, I referred to 198 df in the original dataset that I am working on. Here, in this simulated dataset, df=1 for `lm` output and `lme4` also reported df=1 in the output (for the effect of condition)

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of whether or not the results are the same, the interpretation is still wildly different. If you look at the summary of the `lm` output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = itemMean ~ condition, data = dfWide)

Residuals:
         1          2          3 
 7.500e+00 -7.500e+00  8.882e-16 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)    37.50       7.50   5.000    0.126
conditionb     12.50      12.99   0.962    0.512

Residual standard error: 10.61 on 1 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4808,    Adjusted R-squared:  -0.03846 
F-statistic: 0.9259 on 1 and 1 DF,  p-value: 0.5122
```

There are several things that stick out. The standard error, t, and p values are totally different. There is obviously no summary of the random variance estimated by the model. There is an R-squared and adjusted R-squared value which simply doesn't exist in LMM (see: pseudo and part R2 for mixed models in important papers by Nakagawa). Compare that to the LMM output:

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method [
lmerModLmerTest]
Formula: y ~ condition + (1 | id) + (1 | item)
   Data: dfLong

REML criterion at convergence: 55

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.0337 -0.7261  0.1059  0.4454  1.2749 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id       (Intercept) 93.06    9.647   
 item     (Intercept) 33.33    5.774   
 Residual             58.33    7.638   
Number of obs: 9, groups:  id, 3; item, 3

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error     df t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)   37.500      8.207  1.363   4.569   0.0869 .
conditionb    12.500     12.990  1.000   0.962   0.5122  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
           (Intr)
conditionb -0.528
```

The biggest part you may have missed is this section:

```
   Random effects:
     Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
     id       (Intercept) 93.06    9.647   
     item     (Intercept) 33.33    5.774   
     Residual             58.33    7.638   
    Number of obs: 9, groups:  id, 3; item, 3
```

There is considerable variance by item and by id now. The fixed effect estimates of SE and all other important data is also different.